# Improving a Linear Algebra Proof

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that if $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix with rank m, then there is an $n\times m$ matrix $B$ such that $AB=I_m$ (where $I_m$ is the identity matrix with dimensions $m\times m$).

My proof is as follows:

If $A$ has rank $m$, then the columns of $A$ span $\mathbb{R}^m$. If the columns of $A$ span $\mathbb{R}^m$, then a matrix $B$ can be chosen such that $AB=I_m$, because multiplying $A$ by $B$ is equivalent to taking $m$ linear combinations of the columns of $A$.

My proof does not seem solid. How can I improve it to be more clear and solid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your proof is pretty solid. If you want to make it more explicit, you can do so as follows:

---

Let $e_1,\dots,e_m$ denote the standard basis vectors of $\Bbb R^m$, and let $A_1,\dots,A_n$ denote the columns of $A$.  If $A$ has rank $m$, then the columns of $A$ span $\mathbb{R}^m$.  Thus, for each $j = 1,\dots,m$, we may select $b_{ij}$ for $i = 1,\dots,n$ such that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n b_{ij}A_i = e_j
$$
Let $B$ be the matrix given by $B = (b_{ij})_{i=1}^n{}_{j=1}^m$.  Following the definition of matrix multiplication, we note that $AB = I_m$, as desired.